# How to send string that is html as html file?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express application that gets the html source code from an url, adds modifications to the source code(such as adding a new css properties through `<style></style>`) and then sends the html file through `res.sendFile()`

At the moment I am writing the html files to the disk and then sending. I was wondering if there is a way to bypass that?

```
request(
        { uri: url,
            },
        function(error, response, body) {

            fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/Public/"+ randomint + ".html", newbody, function(err) {

                res.sendFile(__dirname +"/Public/"+randomint+".html")


                if(err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }


            });
```

Comment: are you setting a header before printing the file to the screen?

Comment: Yes I tried doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. First

```
const Readable = require('stream').Readable;
```

And than replace your function with something like

```
function (req,res,body) {
 const s = new Readable();
 s.push(newbody); 
 s.push(null);
 res.header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
 res.pipe(s);
}
```